# mat1 and mat2 must have the same dtype

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, data-science

I'm trying to build a neural network to predict per-capita-income for counties in US based on the education level of their citizens.
X and y have the same dtype (I have checked this) but I'm getting an error.
Here is my data:

```
   county_FIPS state          county  per_capita_personal_income_2019  \
0        51013    VA   Arlington, VA                            97629   

   per_capita_personal_income_2020  per_capita_personal_income_2021  \
0                           100687                           107603    

   associate_degree_numbers_2016_2020  bachelor_degree_numbers_2016_2020  \
0                               19573                             132394
```

And here is my network

```
import torch
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("./input/US counties - education vs per capita personal income - results-20221227-213216.csv")
X = torch.tensor(df[["bachelor_degree_numbers_2016_2020", "associate_degree_numbers_2016_2020"]].values)
y = torch.tensor(df["per_capita_personal_income_2020"].values)

X.dtype
torch.int64

y.dtype
torch.int64

import torch.nn as nn
class BaseNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_dim, hidden_dim, out_dim):
        super(BaseNet, self).__init__()
        self.classifier = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(in_dim, hidden_dim, bias=True), 
        nn.ReLU(), 
        nn.Linear(feature_dim, out_dim, bias=True))
        
    def forward(self, x): 
        return self.classifier(x)

from torch import optim
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
in_dim, hidden_dim, out_dim = 2, 20, 1
lr = 1e-3
epochs = 40
loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
classifier = BaseNet(in_dim, hidden_dim, out_dim)
optimizer = optim.SGD(classifier.parameters(), lr=lr)

def train(classifier, optimizer, epochs, loss_fn):
    classifier.train()
    losses = []
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        out = classifier(X)
        loss = loss_fn(out, y)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        losses.append(loss/len(X))
        print("Epoch {} train loss: {}".format(epoch+1, loss/len(X)))
    
    plt.plot([i for i in range(1, epochs + 1)])
    plt.xlabel("Epoch")
    plt.ylabel("Training Loss")
    plt.show()

train(classifier, optimizer, epochs, loss_fn)
```

Here is the full stack trace of the error that I am getting when I try to train the network:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [77], in <cell line: 39>()
     36     plt.ylabel("Training Loss")
     37     plt.show()
---> 39 train(classifier, optimizer, epochs, loss_fn)

Input In [77], in train(classifier, optimizer, epochs, loss_fn)
     24 losses = []
     25 for epoch in range(epochs):
---> 26     out = classifier(X)
     27     loss = loss_fn(out, y)
     28     loss.backward()

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1194, in Module._call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1190 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1191 # this function, and just call forward.
   1192 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1193         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1194     return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1195 # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1196 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

Input In [77], in BaseNet.forward(self, x)
     10 def forward(self, x): 
---> 11     return self.classifier(x)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1194, in Module._call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1190 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1191 # this function, and just call forward.
   1192 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1193         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1194     return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1195 # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1196 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py:204, in Sequential.forward(self, input)
    202 def forward(self, input):
    203     for module in self:
--> 204         input = module(input)
    205     return input

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1194, in Module._call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1190 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1191 # this function, and just call forward.
   1192 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1193         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1194     return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1195 # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1196 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py:114, in Linear.forward(self, input)
    113 def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 114     return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)

RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 must have the same dtype
```

## Updates

I have tried casting X and y to float tensors but this comes up with the following error: `expected scalar type Long but found Float`. If someone who knows PyTorch could try running this notebook for themselves that would be a great help. I'm struggling to get off the ground with Kaggle and ML.

Comment: [Show us](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the full stacktrace, along with any `.dtypes` debug output you feel could be useful.

Comment: I guess your input is not same dtype as the model’s parameters dtype

Comment: I suggest you show the whole code, including how you handle the data before training

Comment: You should probably conver `x` to a float

Comment: But the data is integers no?

Comment: The full code is up now

Answer (score 4):

The reason for this is because the parameters dtype of `nn.Linear` doesn't match your input's dtype; the default dtype for `nn.Linear` is `torch.float32` which is in your case different from your input data - `float64`.

The solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67456368/pytorch-getting-runtimeerror-found-dtype-double-but-expected-float) solves your problem and explains why @Anonymous answer works.

In short, add `self.double()` at the end of your constructor and things should run.

Answer (score 2):

I converted the input to np.float32 which solved a similar problem for me

Answer (score 0):

Convert tensor array object into float32 if it float64

Before:

```
model(X_train) # float64
```

After:

```
model(X_train.to(torch.float32)) # float32
```