# Darts-NBEATS Error in a multivariate approach RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 must have the same dtype

Tags: python, pytorch, neural-network, time-series

I am trying to train a multivariate NBEATS model on `Darts` (please can we create a tag specifically for Darts? My reputation is too low for doing it).

When I am training the model It returns me this error message:

```
RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 must have the same dtype
```

With this stacktrace:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-144-367da33d5b60> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 model.fit(series = ts_ttrain,
      2           past_covariates = cov_t,
      3           val_series=ts_ttest,
      4           val_past_covariates = cov_t,
      5           verbose = True)

25 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py in forward(self, input)
    112 
    113     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 114         return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
    115 
    116     def extra_repr(self) -> str:

RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 must have the same dtype
```

Similar to these two questions:
[mat1 and mat2 must have the same dtype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75102134/mat1-and-mat2-must-have-the-same-dtype)

[Pytorch getting RuntimeError: Found dtype Double but expected Float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67456368/pytorch-getting-runtimeerror-found-dtype-double-but-expected-float)

My input variables are like it follows:

```
model.fit(series = ts_ttrain,
          past_covariates = cov_t,
          val_series=ts_ttest,
          val_past_covariates = cov_t,
          verbose = True)
```

Where

`ts_train` is a `<class 'darts.timeseries.TimeSeries'>`
`cov_t` is a `<class 'darts.timeseries.TimeSeries'>`
`ts_ttest` is a `<class 'darts.timeseries.TimeSeries'>`

I also tried to inspect them to get more info on the datatype contained inside the `TimeSeries` object, but proably is a wrong approach:

```
print(len([type(x) for x in ts_train]))
print(set([type(x) for x in ts_train]))
print(len([type(x) for x in cov_t]))
print(set([type(x) for x in cov_t]))
print(len([type(x) for x in ts_ttest]))
print(set([type(x) for x in ts_ttest]))
```

with this output:

```
2713
{<class 'darts.timeseries.TimeSeries'>}
3262
{<class 'darts.timeseries.TimeSeries'>}
549
{<class 'darts.timeseries.TimeSeries'>}
```

Here additional information on the regressors I tried to provide to the model:

```
first and last row of unscaled covariates:
component   temp  weather_main  hour  day_of_week  month    year  holidays
Day Index                                                                 
2015-01-01  9.44          0.00  0.00         3.00   1.00 2015.00      1.00
2023-12-06 21.49          1.00  0.00         2.00  12.00 2023.00      0.00
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 3262 entries, 2015-01-01 to 2023-12-06
Freq: D
Data columns (total 7 columns):
 #   Column        Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------        --------------  -----  
 0   temp          3092 non-null   float64
 1   weather_main  3092 non-null   float64
 2   hour          3262 non-null   float64
 3   day_of_week   3262 non-null   float64
 4   month         3262 non-null   float64
 5   year          3262 non-null   float64
 6   holidays      3262 non-null   float64
dtypes: float64(7)
```

You can access to the full code and dataset here:

### **[Stack_Question_website_user_prediction_nbeats](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1d9meSXFPhXhFJaYV_V2mP6oUxS-uQepJ?usp=sharing)**

While I was working as univariate series, without taking into account weather and temperature, my code worked properly, but now I am facing this issue.

---

No sensitive data are shared.

I can try to improve the [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if is needed, it was just more convenient to directly share the colab